# bootstrap datepicker: on 'show' event set selected date on calendar popup as today date

Tags: jquery, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I have `15-Dec-2018` date set in an input field that is associated with a bootstrap datepicker. When I focus on that input field, bootstrap picker pops up with `15-Dec-2018` as selected date (because it was set in associated input field).

[image]

But I want my **own** date to be selected in bootstrap datepicker no matter what date is set in associated field. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

**Here is my solution -**

You can set your own date in the second parameter just replace **'now'** with **new Date('2019-12-3')**

```
Or you should also add first

<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

var date = new Date(); 
var today = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate());
$('#my-datepicker').datepicker('setDate', today);
```

Comment: Please elaborate more on the answer. Where is this `datepicker()` function come from? and remember to format the code.

Comment: @Hitesh that will set the date in textbox as well. I don't want to change the date in textbox. I just want to highlight my own date in the calendar popup.

Comment: I edited my answer now you can try once again.if any problem than tell me.